# Monitor cachetools caches in Python

Tags: python, caching

We are utilizing [cachetools](https://github.com/tkem/cachetools/) in various places in a Python (Flask) application. But we are totally blind to how our caches perform (size, hit/miss rate etc).

Are there any existing solutions to tracking the status of cachetools caches?

I could probably implement something my self, but it seems like a problem that should be solved already.